# Error: Class advice impossible in Python3 topia.termextract

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, google-colaboratory, keyword-search

I am performing an nlp task. I have written the following code for topia.termextract. While executing it isshowing errors. It will be helpful, if you suggest to resolve the errors.

```
from topia.termextract import extract
from topia.termextract import tag

# Setup Term Extractor
extractor = extract.TermExtractor()

# Some sample text
text ='''
Police shut Palestinian theatre in Jerusalem.

Israeli police have shut down a Palestinian theatre in East Jerusalem.

The action, on Thursday, prevented the closing event of an international
literature festival from taking place."""

# Extract Keywords
keywords_topica = extractor(text)
print(keywords_topica)
```

I am using Python 3 in google colab.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------      
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)      
<ipython-input-23-9a094f024dfe> in <module>()      
 ----> 1 from topia.termextract import extract    
       2 from topia.termextract import tag     

 3 frames      
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zope/interface/declarations.py in implements(*interfaces)    
     481     # the coverage for this block there. :(     
     482     if PYTHON3:     
 --> 483         raise TypeError(_ADVICE_ERROR % 'implementer')    
     484     _implements("implements", interfaces, classImplements)    
     485      

     TypeError: Class advice impossible in Python3.  Use the @implementer class decorator instead.
```

Comment: Hello, Did you figure this out? The answer provided didnt help.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, I added the following line:

`from zope.interface import implementer`

to both:

`~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/topia/termextract/extract.py`

and:

`~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/topia/termextract/tag.py`

.

Then in extract.py, I changed

```
class TermExtractor(object):
    zope.interface.implements(interfaces.ITermExtractor)
```

to:

```
@implementer(interfaces.ITermExtractor)
class TermExtractor(object):
    ...
```

And similarly, in tag.py,

```
class Tagger(object):
    zope.interface.implements(interfaces.ITagger)
```

to:

```
@implementer(interfaces.ITagger)
class Tagger(object):
    ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: says implementer is not defined.

Comment: should add ```from zope.interface import implementer```
to tag and extract files.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps solved the issue for me,

```
pip uninstall apex
git clone https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex
cd apex
python3 setup.py install
```